# Show 2 content types in a view that share same field value

Tags: views

Hi i have 2 content types:

- **Agent**
- **Organisation**

they both have fields for id:

- **ID** ( agent content type)
- **Org ID** ( Organisation content type)

Now i need to create a view that will list fields from both of the content types, and only relation between them is same value in fields ( **field_id** and **field_org_id** ).

Since content is already there and there are more than 200 nodes in each content type, i need to work with what i have. That means i cant add new fields ( like node reference ).

Is there a way to make a view that will list fields from two content types that share same value in 2 fields with different name? And in each row to have mix of fields from both content type with relation of this ID.

Comment: try adding both of those fields ID and Org ID in FILTERS.

Answer (score 1):

Since **field_id** and **field_org_id** are two separate fields, you'll need some way to tie them together. A custom entity could do that, but you could also cheat a little and use a taxonomy vocabulary that contains these two fields.

You could then build a view that displays all content and add a relation to the vocabulary and restrict the results to only the content that possesses this relationship.

Cheaty, but I think it might be the easiest solution.

Edit:

I wouldn't modify the content or content types, but rather, add the **field_id** and **field_org_id** fields to the taxonomy vocabulary, then iterate through your **Agent** and **Organization** nodes and generate taxonomy terms that associate one field's value to another by populating each term's **field_id** and **field_org_id** fields from their respective **Agent** and **Organization** nodes.

So, some code...

### Create the vocabulary

```
$vocab = new stdClass();
$vocab->name = 'Organization to Agents';
$vocab->machine_name = 'org_to_agents';
taxonomy_vocabulary_save($vocab);
```

### Add the fields

```
$fields = array(
    'field_id',
    'field_org_id',
);

foreach($fields as $field) {
  // Replace my)taxonomy_vocabulary with your chosen vocabulary name.
  if (is_null(field_info_instance('taxonomy_term', $field, 'my_taxonomy_vocabulary'))) {
    field_create_instance(array(
      'label' => $t($field),  // <-- This doesn't need to be pretty.
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'textfield',
      ),
      'field_name' => $field,
      'entity_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
      'bundle' => 'my_taxonomy_vocabulary',
    ));
  }
}
```

### Get the list of IDs

```
// Credits to https://www.drupal.org/node/1079616#comment-10864932 for example.
$agents = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type", array(':type' => 'agent'))
  ->fetchCol();
$orgs = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE type = :type", array(':type' => 'organization'))
  ->fetchCol();

// Should result in a list of unique Node IDs that exist in
// at least one node for both content types.
$nids = array_intersect($agents, $orgs);
```

### Create your taxonomy terms

```
$vocab = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('my_taxonomy_vocabulary');
foreach($nids as $key => $nid) {
  $term = (object)array(
    'name' => $key, // Use any unique value that makes sense here.
    'vid' => $vocab->vid,
  );
  $term->field_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $nid;
  $term->field_org_id[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $nid;
  taxonomy_term_save($term);
}
```

Again, this is a bit "cheaty", and a custom entity would probably be considered more proper, but I think this should help.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok taxonomy vocabulary sounds doable, but can you explain a bit more how to implement it.

Should i add new field in both of the content types and than somehow map it to this existing or something else?

Comment: Alex, I've updated my answer with some code and additional explanation.